# We are such stuff (as) dreams are made on

Tags: relative-clauses, elision

*We are such stuff (**as**) dreams are made on*

Is *as* optional here?

CONTEXT

*We are such stuff as dreams are made on* (Shakespeare, The Tempest, Act 4, scene 1, modernized spelling).

In sentences of this type such is followed by **as** and not by a relative pronoun **that, who**, etc.: *The federal government has only **such** powers **as** are given to it by the states*.

However, the construction **such ... that** ... indicates the consequence of a stated circumstance: *The flooding has caused **such** hardship **that** the region will need a great deal of government aid*.

Comment: Your question needs more context than that. Where have you find this sentence, could you provide a link? Also, it helps if you explain your doubts.

Comment: For [***most of the last couple of centuries***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+dreams+are+made+on%2Cas+dreams+are+made+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) the line being cited here has nearly always ended with the preposition ***of***. I don't know why around 1860 a few people started replacing ***of*** with ***on*** (which strikes me as syntactic garbage). Perhaps the thinking was "Since it's Shakespeare, it ***ought*** to sound odd", but usually in such contexts any "historical revision" tends to favour using ***more*** natural phrasing.. Weird.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does that matter? What Shakespeare wrote is what counts: https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php I have never heard of editing Shakespeare's quotes myself. 16th century English is not today's English, ergo, it is not garbage. Today's natural phrasing is just wrong. Also, you didn't search the entire thing, did  you?

Comment: @Lambie: I haven't looked into this one specifically, but there are many cases where we're not sure exactly the Bard himself wrote. Heck! - we've only got half-a-dozen instances of him writing his own name, and I'm pretty sure ***every one of those is different***, Regardless of that, I think even if every copy of this text had ***on*** rather than ***of***, and we were *certain* that was the original, I still think ***learners*** would be well served by knowing that's not the preposition we'd normally use ***today***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Most commentators explain that it means according to Elizabethan usage, as indeed it may, " made of." But it may also mean just what it says
to the unlearned modern mind. Whether we are such stuff as dreams are
made of is at best a matter of opinion or conviction. But that we are such stuff as dreams are made on is a matter of fact.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 2) It is indeed the one datum
of consciousness more nearly ultimate even than Descartes's Cogito, ergo
sum. Perhaps the final secret and definition of matter will turn out to be not
some mathematical formula but simply this: Matter is that stuff on which
dreams can be imprinted, that substance on which creative
energy can be projected.

Comment: @Lambie 3) How else could things as frail as dreams have
survived the tempest and chaos of material evolution?
A question that contains its own answer.  https://books.google.es/books?id=UwXjq8zwYIIC&lpg=PA291&dq=%22dreams%20are%20made%20on%22&hl=es&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q=%22dreams%20are%20made%20on%22&f=false

Comment: @Lambie, GJC: If you didn't already know it, you might be interested to note that a couple of centuries after the original, Keats *Endymion* has *Of that fine element that visions, dreams, And fitful whims of sleep **are made of***. It seems pretty clear to me that Keats was deliberately echoing Shakespeare there, so he obviously either knew a different version of the original himself, ***or*** he had no problem "correcting" it to the preposition that he felt was more idiomatic even then.

Comment: @GJC Yesterday, a lawyer tried to hornswoggle me and today, I come here and see that the OP has edited the question **after** the fact to use my answer to update her/his own without attribution. Well, them's the breaks, I guess. **on** means **from** also, in Elizabethan English: https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Glossary.aspx?Id=12003

Answer (score 2):

That is a Shakespeare quote:

Prospero:
Our revels now are ended. These our actors,
As I foretold you, were all spirits, and
Are melted into air, into thin air:
And like the baseless fabric of this vision,
The cloud-capp'd tow'rs, the gorgeous palaces,
The solemn temples, the great globe itself,
Yea, all which it inherit, shall dissolve,
And, like this insubstantial pageant faded,
Leave not a rack behind. **We are such stuff

As dreams are made on**; and our little life
Is rounded with a sleep.

[Shakespeare's The Tempest](https://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/we-such-stuff-dreams-made)

My advice is: **Never mess with the Bard**.

[A joke but true: Whatever he says, I quote]

Answer (score 0):

such … as

is a perfectly good construction in modern English, but, at least in modern American English, the construction would not be natural to express this particular thought.

> We are the stuff that dreams are made from

would be more likely. You are of course quoting something that was written before there was a UK, let alone a USA. It is technically modern English, but of a type that has not been spoken or written in centuries.

But the locution is still used in language of a formal register, and the “as” is necessary to that construction.

> Such comments as Trump’s latest contribute to the current bitterness of political dispute.

Comment: _The federal government has only **such** powers **as**_ [not _*that_] _are given to it by the states_.

Comment: That  is tracking language written well over two hundred years ago.  And I specifically said that the “such … as” construction requires the “as.” So what you quote is not a contradiction to my answer. My additional point is that what would sound less archaic is “The federal government has only the powers that are granted to it by the states.” It is clear that you do not find my answers helpful so I shall not bother you further.